# PHP code with $_GET function is not working, no errors

Tags: php, get, isset

I have written a simple PHP code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['day']) && isset($_GET['date']) && isset($GET['year'])) {
        $day = $_GET['day'];
        $date = $_GET['date'];
        $year = $_GET['year'];
        if (!empty($day) && !empty($date) && !empty($year)) {
            echo 'It is '.$day.' '.$date.' '.$year;
        } else {
            echo 'Fill in all fields.';
        }
    }
?>

<form action="index.php" method="GET">
    Day:<br><input type="text" name="day"><br>
    Date:<br><input type="text" name="date"><br>
    Year:<br><input type="text" name="year"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To me, everything looks OK. No errors after running. But, neither the output. Non of the echos shows up. Form is there and I enter data, but when I click "Submit", it just stays the same. URL of the page changes and I can see entered data there, but no echos on the page. I have checked the code for spelling errors, and I haven't found any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use this too `if ( isset($_GET['day'], $_GET['date'], $_GET['year']) ) {`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot an underscore at this:

```
 if (isset($_GET['day']) && isset($_GET['date']) && isset($GET['year'])) {
```

at the last get

```
 if (isset($_GET['day']) && isset($_GET['date']) && isset($_GET['year'])) {
```

Comment: FFS, how could I miss that. :facepalm:

Comment: 15 sec faster .. that is nice

Comment: @user1687538, that happens me to sometimes... i call it code blind. THen you've looked to long at code that you don't see something like that anymore :D

Comment: @user1687538, can you mark the answer as real anser? so users in the future can see verry simple what the answer is...

Answer (score 4):

It is [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) not `$GET`

You need to add an underscore:

```
$GET['year']
```

to:

```
$_GET['year']
```